# How to use Kinde Auth to secure two NextJS apps?

Tags: next.js, oauth-2.0

I am building a Next.JS application, where I am using Kinde Auth for authentication. This app is a headless ecommerce CMS where users can create products, variants etc...
I want to expose a route handler that will be a public API Endpoint where users can access their account specific data from other client apps (For example a web app or another ecommerce application). I need some sort of method of authorization. I thought about creating API Keys for users or tokens, but honestly I don't know what is the best practice of doing this and all the information I find suggests using one of Oauth2 authorization flow for this kind of thing but I never implemented Oauth2 before and I am not sure how to do it. I also saw that Kinde Auth offers the possibility of protecting API's but this doesn't seem to be the perfect case for me. Take the following scenario:
If a user creates an ecommerce storefront using a framework like Next.JS and wants to access his products from my application by hitting the API endpoint what would be best practice to authorize his request?